# Automatically unfreeze a room when a mod posts a message

Tags: feature-request, chat, frozen-rooms

It appears that mods can post to a room even when it's frozen, which could result in the false assumption that the room is not frozen. This would be particularly bad for "contact a mod" chatrooms. I'd recommend changing the logic to automatically remove a freeze when a moderator posts a message to the room.

Comment: Yea, especially when the message is "We needed to freeze this room so emotions could cool a bit" ;)

Comment: @Mołot There's a separate timout feature for such a case that blocks any non-mod from talking for a specified amount of time.

Comment: Counter feature: Freeze the room any time a mod logs in. Makes more sense, semantically.